# Cannot set a different colormap for each subplot

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, subplot, colormap

The colormap function in my code should give 3 different colormaps for 3 subplots. I have been using the [`polarmap`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/37099) colormap since last year to show the Doppler profile. I've just discovered that it is not working anymore! All three subplots are now in same colormap which is the first one: "hot".

Note: Recently I updated my MATLAB from 2017 to 2018. I am not sure whether it may cause such error.

Below is my code:

```
% Intensity, Doppler, Line width
f2 = figure();
set(f2,'position', [0, 0, screenX, screenY])

sx1 = subplot(1,3,1);
imagesc(x,t,(meanxytint'))
set(gca,'YDir','normal')
colormap hot
colorbar
caxis([0 5000])

xlabel('Solar X','FontSize',14,'FontWeight','bold')
ylabel('Solar Y','FontSize',14,'FontWeight','bold')
title('Intensity (DN)', 'FontSize', 16);
ax = gca;
ax.XAxis.FontSize = 12;
ax.YAxis.FontSize = 12;

sx2 = subplot(1,3,2);
imagesc(x,t,meanxytdop')
set(gca,'YDir','normal')
colormap (sx2, flipud(polarmap(1024)))
colorbar
caxis([-100 100])

xlabel('Solar X','FontSize',14,'FontWeight','bold')
ylabel('Solar Y','FontSize',14,'FontWeight','bold')
title('Doppler Profile (km/s)', 'FontSize', 16);
ax = gca;
ax.XAxis.FontSize = 12;
ax.YAxis.FontSize = 12;

sx3 = subplot(1,3,3);
imagesc(x,t,meanxytwid')
set(gca,'YDir','normal')
colormap gray
colorbar
caxis([0 150])

xlabel('Solar X','FontSize',14,'FontWeight','bold')
ylabel('Solar Y','FontSize',14,'FontWeight','bold')
title('Non-thermal Cont. (km/s)', 'FontSize', 16);
ax = gca;
ax.XAxis.FontSize = 12;
ax.YAxis.FontSize = 12;
```

Comment: can you add some dummy data to provide a [mcve]? Also, you are saying that this did not happen in 2017 and does happen in 2018?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is this line:

```
colormap gray
```

Note that in the first two axes you use the axes handle to set the colormap, e.g.

```
colormap (sx2, flipud(polarmap(1024)))
```

From the [documentation of `colormap`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) (emphasis mine):

> `colormap map` sets the colormap for the current **figure** to one of the predefined colormaps. If you set the colormap for the figure, then **axes and charts in the figure use the same colormap**.

The fix is easy, just use the same syntax as in the other cases:

```
colormap(sx3, gray);
```

---

Some other notes:

- If you want to maximize you figure, do

  ```
  f2 = figure('WindowState', 'maximized');
  ```
- There's no need to do `ax = gca` when you already have the axes handle (`sx1...3`).